# C++ segmentation fault when I have an Array inside an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I tried to implement my own class named Array that act mostly like a vector because I don't want to use std. It works well with basic classes but when I want to instantiate an Array of a class that contains an Array (class Scene for exemple) it stops the program saying "Windows stoped fonctionning"... When I try to search for the error with break points I saw that it says "segmentation fault" when the program is at the destructor.

Here's my classes :

Array.h

```
#ifndef NAME_ARRAY_H
#define NAME_ARRAY_H

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include "malloc.h"

template <class T>
class Array {
private:
T *m_array;
unsigned int m_tot_size;
unsigned int m_actual_size;
public:
Array(unsigned int size);
Array(Array<T> const& paste);

bool add(T var);
const T& get(unsigned int index);
bool remove(unsigned int index);
void kill();

unsigned int getActualSize() const;
unsigned int getTotalSize() const;
T* getArray() const;

T& operator[](unsigned int index);
Array<T>& operator=(Array<T> const& paste);


~Array();

};

//CONSTRUCTOR
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(unsigned int size) : m_tot_size(size), m_actual_size(0) {
m_array = (T*) malloc(size * sizeof(T));
}

template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(Array<T> const &paste) : m_tot_size(paste.m_tot_size), 
m_actual_size(paste.m_actual_size) {
m_array = new T(*(paste.m_array));
}

//METHODES PUBLIC
template <class T>
const T & Array<T>::get(unsigned int index) {
if (index >= m_actual_size || index < 0)
    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
return m_array[index];
}

template <class T>
bool Array<T>::remove(unsigned int index) {
if(index < m_actual_size && m_actual_size != 0) {
    m_actual_size--;
    m_array[index] = m_array[m_actual_size];

    return true;
}
return false;
}

template <class T>
bool Array<T>::add(T obj) {
if (m_actual_size >= m_tot_size) {
    T *temp;
    temp = (T*) realloc(m_array,5*sizeof(T));
    m_array = temp;
    m_array[m_actual_size] = obj;
    m_actual_size++;
    m_tot_size += 5;
    return false;
} else {
    m_array[m_actual_size] = obj;
    m_actual_size++;
    return true;
}
}

template <class T>
void Array<T>::kill() {
free(m_array);
delete [] m_array;
m_array = nullptr;

m_actual_size = 0;
m_tot_size = 0;
}

//ACCESSOR

template <class T>
unsigned int Array<T>::getActualSize() const { return m_actual_size; }

template <class T>
unsigned int Array<T>::getTotalSize() const { return m_tot_size; }

template <class T>
T* Array<T>::getArray() const { return m_array; }


//OPERATOR

template <class T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](unsigned int index) { return m_array[index]; }

template <class T>
Array<T>& Array<T>::operator=(Array<T> const& paste) {
if(this != &paste) {
    m_tot_size = paste.m_tot_size;
    m_actual_size = paste.m_actual_size;

    free(m_array);
    delete [] m_array;
    m_array = nullptr;

    m_array = new T(*(paste.m_array));
}
return *this;
}

//DESTRUCTOR
template <class T>
Array<T>::~Array() {
    free(m_array);
    delete [] m_array;
    m_array = nullptr;
}
```

Scene.cpp :

```
#include "Scene.h"

Scene::Scene(std::string sceneName) : m_name(sceneName), m_array_position(20) {
}


void Scene::update() {}

void Scene::render() {}


Scene::~Scene() {
//m_array_position.kill();
//m_array_systems.kill();
}
```

Scene.h

```
#ifndef NAME_SCENE_H
#define NAME_SCENE_H

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "../components/Position.h"
#include "../utils/Array.h"
#include "../systems/System.h"

class Scene {
private:
std::string m_name;
Array<Position> m_array_position;

public:
Scene(std::string sceneName);
void update();
void render();
~Scene();
};
```

main

```
Array<Scene> scenes(1);
```

I think the problem is that the program destroy the Array and then try to destroy the Array (Position is just a struct) but I'm not sure and I don't know what to do to correct it. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: why dont you want to use vectors? I hope the reason is only to exercise

Comment: @user463035818 As I said I don't want to use std, but yeah don't worry it's just practice ^^

Comment: you are mixing `malloc`, `new` and `delete []`. I usually try to stay away from such horrible stuff, but I would suspect the error is somewhere there. `new` should go with `delelete`,  `new []` with `delete []`  and `malloc` with `free`, mixing them in any other combinations is calling for troubles afaik

Comment: "I don't want to use std" - *Why on earth not*? That's the (sorry) dumbest thing I've heard in a long time. The `std::` stuff is most likely *better* and more *well tested* than anything you could write yourself, plus it's available *everywhere* as part of your compilers runtime. Why you wouldn't want to use it *I* cannot fathom. Please explain.

Comment: @user463035818 yeah; mixing them is UB.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Cause when you import std the whole std library is imported and it's a bit heavy (plus I don't like vectors). I want to try my own classes to see if it can be a great thing. But as I mentionned, it's mostly praticte for now

Comment: there is nothing such as "import the whole std library" in c++. You just include the headers you need.

Comment: @Kolopox "Cause when you import std the whole std library is imported" - No it is not. Not unless you are doing it wrong. Where did you get that notion? You can include just the bits you need/use. Also; learn to *love* `std::vector`, it's just about the best, most useful and *fastest* container available.

Comment: let me give you an advice from someone who resisted to use `std::vector` for much too long: Dont be stubborn and start using it now. I dont remember a single segfault in my code since I stopped to write c with classes and started to use the standard library. If this alone isnt reason enough for you then I really dont know what to say more....

Comment: A quick clarification on one of user463035818's comments. Sadly there is such a thing as importing the whole standard library in some C++ implementations and it is a really, really bad idea for many more reasons than just the size. It does exist, so don't be surprised when you do find it. Don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see in a lot of places code like this:

```
free(m_array);
delete [] m_array;
```

This doesn't look good to me. When allocating and deallocating memory, you have to match the allocation method with the deallocation:

- If you reserve memory with "malloc", you free it with "free"
- If you reserve with "new", you deallocate with "delete"
- If you reserve with "new []", then you free with "delete []"

You should only use one of the methods or, if you REALLY need to mix them, then you should keep something tracking which method you would need to free the memory.

Comment: But with modern C++, should not need to use malloc/free, or new[]/delete[], or new/delete anyway.  There are better options in the language.  (Sure, the allocators are used under the covers, but the programmer ought not to need them except in a very few situations.)

Comment: Well, I bet there are special cases where you must need some of these. But maybe Kolopox is doing this for educational purposes. It is always good to know how the things behind the scenes.

Comment: In addition, when using `malloc/free` for arrays, destructors should be called manually on each of the elements in the array before freeing. `delete []` takes care of this automatically.

Comment: @JorgeY. Thanks, yeah I confused things a bit... When I tried with just malloc it worked great ! I'm happy it was only that ^^ Thanks a lot

Comment: @Kolopox If you are using `malloc` and `free` with C++ objects you are doing it wrong. Those functioms don't call constructors/destructors - your C++ objects won't get correctly created nor destroyed - this *will* bite you later, even if it may *seem* to work now.

Comment: Also; using manual `new`/`delete` (and equivalent) in modern C++ is a code smell in almost every case. One should use containers and smart pointers - *not* manual memory management.